# Adding to an array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm currently writing a ruby function that gets a table from a database and then based on the data creates an array. It's written like this:

```
  def listSome
    @foos = Array.new
    FooTable.find(:all) do |foo|
      @foos << foo if foo.name == "Bar"
    end
  end
```

The problem I'm having is that only the first element of the query is getting added to the array. I've checked that FooTable.find(:all) returns what I think it should in the console and also that it's ok to loop off of it's results (I printed the results on every loop, it found what it was looking for). I suspect, however, there is something about concatenation to arrays/collections that I don't understand. Why am I only getting the first result of the query added into my array? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are providing a block to the `find` method which isn't going to run it against each element of the array it returns. Provide your block to the `each` method returned by `find`.

```
FooTable.find(:all).each { |foo| ... }
```

Also, assuming this is actual code and not an example, there is a really bad way of getting foos with a specific name.

*rails 2*

```
@foos = FooTable.find(:all, :conditions => ['name = ?', 'Bar'])
```

*rails 3*

```
@foos = FooTable.where('name = ?', 'Bar')
```

Comment: +1  I deleted a similar answer, but didn't mention the inefficiency of his find. I like this this one better.

Comment: Jeez you're right I see it now. Also, would this be any more or less a valid/better/worse approach? @foos = FooTable.find_all_by_name("Bar")?

Comment: Using find_all_by_name would be a perfectly good approach; that's a dynamic helper that would end up being exactly the same as doing the find with a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `each`: `FooTable.find(:all).each do |foo|`.

But I'd make some more comments, you should use more `map/select/reject/inject` and less `each`:

```
def listSome
  @foos = FooTable.find(:all).select do |foo|
    foo.name == "Bar"
  end
end
```

But whenever possible, use more SQL and less Ruby:

```
def listSome
  @foos = FooTable.where(:name => "Bar")
end
```

Comment: Why use `map` and `compact` instead of just a `select`?

Comment: @Samuel, indeed, I wanted to show map, but here select is better.